# C++ Why does my code give the desired results on Ubuntu but has undefined behavior on Windows 7

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I am taking a C++ course in University, every week we are required to write a program with given specifications. It's usually basic tasks that resolve around the topics we discussed in class the week before. As we are discussing pointers arrays and dynamic memory naturally this week's program was all about using arrays and dynamic memory allocation.

To break it down, the program we were asked to write was supposed to take a random user input (no white spaces, just some random characters) and divide the user input in 3 categories: Upper case, lower case and special characters.

The method I used is probably not the most efficient one but it does the job, considering the only libraries we are allowed to use are iostream and cmath, however here comes my problem. In class I wrote the program in almost no time, compiled it and it ran straight away no issues. If you give a user input such as aAghC4 it will have as output AC agh 4

So I went ahead and downloaded my program from my university folder on my private machine at home to work on it a little, make it more efficient as practice. However when I compiled the (unedited and original) .cpp on my windows machine it's output is random, undefined behavior. Both in class and at home I use g++ to compile my files, however at home I run Windows 7, in class we use Ubuntu 14.04.

I would be very greatful if someone could take a look at my code and tell me why it doesn't work on a windows machine.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  char input[80];
  int counter = 0;

  cin >> input;
  for(int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++){
  counter++;
  }

  char *uppercase = new char[counter];
  char *lowercase = new char[counter];
  char *special = new char[counter];

  for(int i = 0; i < (counter+1); i++){
  switch(input[i]){
    case 'a': lowercase[i] = input[i]; break;
    case 'b': lowercase[i] = input[i]; break;
    // I edited this part it basically goes on for the entire
    // alphabet, first lowercase letters then uppercase
    case 'Y': uppercase[i] = input[i]; break;
    case 'Z': uppercase[i] = input[i]; break;
    default: special[i] = input[i]; break;
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i <= counter; i++){
    cout << uppercase[i];
  }

  cout << " ";
  for(int i = 0; i <= counter; i++){
    cout << lowercase[i];
  }

  cout << " ";
  for(int i = 0; i <= counter; i++){
    cout << special[i];
  }

  delete[] uppercase;
  delete[] lowercase;
  delete[] special;
  cout << endl;
}
```

This is the entire source code, nothing more and nothing less, thank you for any replies!

Comment: One think I could see immediately is that it will overflow if the user enters more than 80 characters. Could this be the problem? It would be safer if input were an std::string.

Comment: Second comment... you're accessing your arrays with indices from 0 to counter. Likely this should be from 0 to counter - 1.

Comment: Our assignments are designed in a way in which we can assume the user will input only what the program allows i.e. less than 80 characters and no white spaces. We were also meant to use a char array. We haven't done strings in class yet so technically we are not allowed to use them.

Comment: @Sjlver second comment: But why would it perfectly work on a Ubuntu machine while it has undefined behavior on Windows, despite I use the same compiler for both of them

Comment: The phrase "undefined behavior" has a particular meaning for C/C++ programmers that has to do with whether an operation has a defined behavior as specified in the C or C++ Standards or if the C or C++ Standards say that the behavior generated by an operation is undefined by the Standard hence different compilers may produce different behavior.  What you are describing is an application behavior which is different and most likely caused by a defect in your source code.

Comment: As an aside you could rewrite your massive switch statement if you consider that upper and lowercase characters can be represented in ASCII by ranges. e.g. uppercase is 65 to 90.

Comment: I haven't really looked into ASCII but I knew that somewhere my code is a bit too... inconvenient if that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have *undefined behavior* in both programs, no matter if you run it on *ubuntu* or *windows 7*; you are just *lucky* that it shows the behavior you expected on the former.

---

#### reading uninitialized memory = *undefined behavior*

You are assuming that the valid range of elements to read in all of `uppercase`, `lowercase`, and `special` is that of `[0, counter]` which isn't the case; you are effectively reading uninitialized memory in your loops that iterate over the elements of these arrays (and *undefined behavior* emerge).

The reason you *think* it's working when running the code on *ubuntu* is probably because the memory of your three arrays **happens** to be zero-initialized; meaning that your loops will print a bunch of `'\0'` (normally not visible in a terminal) when you haven't assigned a particular element a value.

```
char * p = new char[counter]   ; // default-initialized `char`s (could have any value)
char * p = new char[counter] (); // value-initialized, all elements are `char()` ie. 0
```

---

#### reading past the end of an array = *undefined behavior*

There's also a problem that your loops that prints the contents of `uppercase`, `lowercase`, and `special` has an *off-by-one* problem.

The last element offset for all of these loops are `counter-1`, but you assume it to be `counter` (`i <= counter`).

---

#### Solution

- Don't print elements which you haven't, explicitly, given a value.

  This can be accomplished by a separate counter for each of your arrays, or some other means (like initializing every element of the arrays to `0` and stop iterating when such value is found).
- Don't read elements that aren't part of the memory you allocated.

Comment: This is the correct answer. He is likely compiling in debug mode at school and in release at home. Another argument that compilers shouldn't zero initialise values in debug.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. @sjdowling I am not sure whether or not the compiler is differently set up in uni but both at home as well as in class I use these parameters:
g++ name.cpp -Wall -o3 -o filename

Comment: Thank you @FilipRoséen-refp I hope my question isn't too dull. I was just puzzled because everything worked fine in class but at home I suddenly have smileys and weird characters on my screen.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the elements in your `uppercase`, `lowercase` etc array are **uninitialized** causing the issue. When you print (read) uninitialized variables or memory, it invokes undefined behaviour. You should have separate counters for all arrays.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  char input[80];
  int counter = 0;
  int u = 0, l = 0, s = 0;

  cin >> input;
  for(int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++){
  counter++;
  }

  char *uppercase = new char[counter];
  char *lowercase = new char[counter];
  char *special = new char[counter];

  for(int i = 0; i < (counter+1); i++){
    if('a' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'a') lowercase[l++] = input[i];
    else if('A' <= input[i] && input[i] <= 'Z') uppercase[u++] = input[i];
    else special[s++] = input[i]; break;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i <= u; i++){
    cout << uppercase[i];
  }

  cout << " ";
  for(int i = 0; i <= l; i++){
    cout << lowercase[i];
  }

  cout << " ";
  for(int i = 0; i <= s; i++){
    cout << special[i];
  }

  delete[] uppercase;
  delete[] lowercase;
  delete[] special;
  cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one error, the for loops have problems.

The one with the switch inside should have a stop condition like `i<counter` not `counter+1`.

Every other following loops should also have a stop condition like `i<counter` not `<=`.

You should also initialize you arrays with some predefined value (ascii NUL for example) :

```
for (i=0; i<counter; i++) lowercase[i] = '\0';
```

and at the end when printing, only print non nul chars :

```
for (i=0; i<counter; i++) if (lowercase[i]!='\0') cout << lowercase[i];
```

Comment: I do i<counter+1 so it loops over every character and doesn't stop at the one before the last one. I guess i<=counter would be the same result.

Same goes for the other for loops. Still I feel like this is not the answer why this code works on a Linux machine but not on a windows machine. Or is it and I just being ignorant to my own mistakes?

Comment: No the last one is `counter-1`... If you have 10 say chars, then their indices are 0..9. Such a mistake leads to an undefined behavior.